# Factory girl: user failing validation despite attributes being valid (using acts as taggable gem)

Tags: validation, rspec, factory-bot

I am getting this error in when I run my user_controller_spec.rb

```
  Failure/Error: login_member
    ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
    Validation failed: User tag list You need to provide at least 5 interests
```

The following code is causing my tests to fail. More specifically the line "login_member"

In user_controller_spec.rb

```
 before(:example) do
   login_member
   @user = @member.user
   @another_user = create(:another_user)
 end
```

Here is my factory set up. You can see a user gets created with the member

Factories.rb

```
factory :member do
   email { Faker::Internet.email }
   password 'fidelio'
   password_confirmation 'fidelio'
   confirmed_at Time.now
   association :user
 end

 factory :user do
  first_name "Simon"
  last_name "Walsh"
  country "GB"
  tag_list = "Sarcoidosis, Clinical trials, Emphysema, Bronchitis, Idiopathic pulmonary fibrosis"
 end
```

And the following helper logs in the member

In spec_helpers.rb

```
def login_member
   @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:member]
   @member = create (:member)
   sign_in @member
end
```

Here is my validation code in my user class. I have specified it only on update.

In user.rb

```
  validate :check_minimum_tags, on: :update

  def check_minimum_tags
   errors.add(:tag_list, 'You need to provide at least 5 interests') unless tag_list.count > 4
  end
```

I am uncertain

1. Why this would be raising an error to begin with as its creating a associated user not updating it
2. Why its being raised anyway....you can see I have specified 5 interests in "tag_list" (using acts with taggable gem)

I have also tried using an array of interests instead of a string

Answer (score 0):

Answer found.....simple syntax error in my factory.

Should be

```
factory :user do
  first_name "Simon"
  last_name "Walsh"
  country "GB"
  tag_list "Sarcoidosis, Clinical trials, Emphysema, Bronchitis, Idiopathic pulmonary fibrosis"
end
```

idiot